# Conditional Number Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a column with numberical values that range from `0` to `1,000,000,000+`. I would like to format the cells to abbreviate based on their value. So far I have this:

```
[>999999999]0.0,,," B";[>999999]0.0,," M";0," K"
```

and that works, but I'd like to add in a condition for anything less than `1000` to show up as `NA`. So far nothing I have tried works. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of excel are you using?  Older versions are limited to 3 conditions.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996846/maximum-number-of-conditional-formatting-rules-in-excel-2016) for a similar question.  Using 3 conditions, the following works [>999999]#,,"M";[>999]#,"K";"NA", if you try to add another, Excel barks out an error.  You might be able to use a formula though if you want to have a second column.

Comment: Actually, that link I posted was more for the Conditional Formatting Rules, but it lead me to test the maximum number of conditions for the number format.  It seems there is a fixed number of parts where normally it would be "positive format;negative format;zero format;text format", and what you're trying is just overriding one of those parts.  But there's something quirky happening if you try to use 4 parts when not a normal format codes.

Comment: @BlueGI, I'm using Excel 2016. I was afraid that the condition limit might be the problem, and I think that could be it because anything I try spits out an error.

Comment: I don't think that's it, isn't the problem just that changing a numerical value to NA isn't formatting? Conditional formatting won't change your cell values, just your formatting.

Comment: @AlexM, The OP is not changing the value of the cell, just what is displayed. Try this custom number format for displaying only numbers from one to ten  [>10]"Too Big";[<1]"Too Small";0

Comment: No kidding. Learn something new every day. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel formatting with user specified criterion conditions the *Alternative Section Arguments* is used with a maximum of three sections rather than the default *Standard Section Arrangement* with its four sections.

(Source:  SumProduct Pty Ltd.)

## [Multiple Number Formatting](https://www.sumproduct.com/thought/multiple-number-formatting)

#### Standard Section Arrangement (min 1 - max 4)

# of Sections - Values in sections

1 - All numerical values
2 - Non-negative numbers; negative numbers
3 - Positive numbers; negative numbers; zero values
4 - Positive numbers; negative numbers; zero values; text

#### Alternative Section Arguments (min 1 - max 3):

# of Sections - Section Details

1 - All numerical values
2 - Numbers meeting criterion; All other values
3 - Numbers meeting first criterion; Numbers meeting second criterion
. . . which do not meet the first criterion; All other values

Comment: Wow, I was literally on the linked page when I saw this. I think the combination approach (custom number format + condtional format) will be the best option.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to add any more conditions to the custom number format already used. One way is to add a conditional formatting with a custom number format such as `[Red]"NA";[Red]"NA";[Red]"NA";[Red]"NA"` with a formula like: `=OR(NOT(ISNUMBER(A1)),A1<1000)` (assuming that the cell is at `A1`)